# Open-source web clipper for Firefox

Tags: open-source, firefox, bookmark, metadata

I'm looking for an open-source addon for Firefox that allows saving web pages along with metadata.  I understand this functionality is similar to [Pocket](http://getpocket.com) or Evernote Web Clipper, but I have not used either.

Essential features:

- Provides a way to save text from a webpage to local disk, by highlighting some text and using a hotkey...
- ...along with the full webpage itself (including images, stylesheets, etc., as in firefox's "Web Page, complete")
- ...and the URL

Features that I DON'T need, nor want (but it's not essential that the addon lacks these features if the code is good and not too big, since then I can remove them myself if needed):

- Saving to 'the cloud'
- Integration with phones or tablets
- Integration with social media systems
- Indexing / searching

Nice to have:

- A way to save tags along with the clip, with a good UI
- Saving a timestamp along with the clip
- Clean code
- A way to run an external program when a clip is saved
- Free (libre) software
- Not too many features
- Saving PDF alongside the web page source

Comment: As you list "Free (libre) software" as "nice to have", do you mean "open-source" (which you seem to require) in the literal sense, i.e., that the source code must be readable (but not necessarily licensed under an Open Source license)?

Comment: @unor: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78958/is-there-a-difference-between-free-software-and-open-source-software

Comment: @unor it should be licensed under an open source license, yes.  It would be best if the maintainer / project worked by free software principles.

Comment: Okay, so you seem to require a license that is approved by the OSI, and you would welcome a license that is *also* approved by the FSF (most are approved by both anyway, but there are very few [exceptions](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/383/138)), right?

Comment: @unor I don't require a license that is approved by the OSI, and I'm neutral on the FSF's approval per se.  I do require something that's open source, and I approve of free software.  Thank you for the questions but that's honestly as specific as I wanted to be: my criteria just aren't that tight.  I'm sure there are already enough nice-to-haves to over-constrain the problem.

Answer (score 4):

[ScrapBook X](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/scrapbook-x/?src=dp-dl-dependencies) is a powerful and improved fork of [ScrapBook](http://www.xuldev.org/scrapbook/). Its [source](https://github.com/danny0838/firefox-scrapbook) is released under the Mozilla Public License Version 2.0.

It **DOES include a keyboard mapping feature** for capturing the selection through a user customizable keyboard combination which is enabled through Tools->Add-ons->Scrapbook X->Preferences in Firefox.

Here are the [features](https://github.com/danny0838/firefox-scrapbook/wiki/Features).

There are a number of add-on helpers that further extend the utility of ScrapBook X.

[Compared to ScrapBook](https://github.com/danny0838/firefox-scrapbook/wiki/Diffs), ScrapBook X emphasizes bug fixes and usability improvements, but also adds new features.

Answer (score 0):

[WebToPDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webtopdf/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming) also a nice option.this addon is free and and No server processing. It will take screenshot of whole page.even include which is not shown currently on-screen (scrolling)